# Есть ли на JS библиотека как phpWord/phpOffice

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, phpword

У меня есть приложение написанное на PHP, чтобы записивать из `json` в `docx`. Мне нуже ее написать с помощью JavaScript.

Подскажите название библиотеки или направьте на ресурс, пожайлуста.

Comment: Конкретизируйте `записивать з json в docx` - это использование объектов для подстановки их свойств в шаблон документа (т.е. нужен шаблонизатор) или для генерации с нуля (тогда нужнен пакет для создания и редактирования документа вручную)?

Comment: документ уже готовый, с айдишками внутри, вместо них надо вписать данние с json массива, и сгенерировать новый docx @Anatoly

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx-templates или https://www.npmjs.com/package/docxtemplater или ещё что-то, что можно найти на npmjs.com.

Comment: Значит нужен темплейтер, например из тех, что указал @nörbörnën

Comment: @nörbörnën Пожалуйста, оформите ответ. Воспрос хороший, в плане того, что новички точно будут его открывать. Можно привести пару примеров библиотек.

Comment: @Anatoly Пожалуйста, оформите ответ. Воспрос хороший, в плане того, что новички точно будут его открывать. Можно привести пару примеров библиотек.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для подстановки определенных свойств из объектов/массивов объектов в DOCX, который используется в качестве шаблона и содержит определенные символы/идентификаторы внутри шаблона, которые и нужно заменить, лучше всего использовать шаблонизатор.

Пример:

```
// объект со свойствами
const templateObject = {
  project: {
    name: 'Test project'
  }
}
```

часть содержимого шаблона DOCX:

```
Наименование проекта: {project.name}
```

Результат:

```
Наименование проекта: Test project
```

В качестве шаблонизаторов можно использовать, например, эти два: [docx-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx-templates) и
[docxtemplater](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docxtemplater)